# Calculate slot percent

Tags: r

example data:

```
0.1,0.22,0.2232,0.4,0.44...1.0,1.0
```

set `binwidth` to `0.1` ,then i have 10 slot:

```
[0,0.1] has 10 points
[0.1,0.2],has 10 points
[0.2,0.3],has 10 points
[0.3,0.4],has 10 points
[0.4,0.5],has 10 points
[0.5,0.6],has 10 points
[0.6,0.7],has 10 points
[0.7,0.8],has 10 points
[0.8,0.9],has 10 points
[0.9,1],has 10 points
```

suppose total points: 100

i want to calculate percentage of every "slot" ...

```
[0,0.1] , 10/100
...
```

is there a library can use in R? or how to write a function for myself because i need call it many times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is such a build-in function in R. However, it's not difficult to write such a function. My idea is trying to use the logic operation between vector and scalar. Here is a simple example

```
intv <- 0.1;
total <- 10/intv;
slots <- seq(from=0, to=(10-intv), by=intv);
data <- seq(from=0, to=10, by=0.01);
result <- vector();

i <- 1;
for (slot in slots){
    result[i] <- sum(data>slot & data<=(slot+intv));
    i <- i+1;
}

result <- result/total;
```

In above, `sum(data>slot & data<=(slot+intv))` is the key expression. Hope it's helpful to you.